# Stream VLC playlist through RTMP live streaming

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, streaming, rtmp

I am just tried to stream my playlist MP4 file to my live stream. I am using play my playlist via VLC and also stream via VLC. I am using the following code :

```
vlc --playlist-autostart --loop  --playlist-tree http://xxxxx.com/test --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=300,fps=25,scale=1,acodec=mp4a,ab=64,channels=2}:std{access=rtmp,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=rtmp://xxxxx.com/xxx/xxx1}'
```

The above code play the playlist file but the streaming is not work . when I am run this code in my Ubuntu command prompt it's return the following error :

```
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x678d58] inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0x678d58] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x678d58] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0x648108] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0x648108] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x678d58] qt4 interface error: Could not connect to X server
[0x678d58] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
[0x678d58] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.

> Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
Using network protocols without global network initialization. Please use avformat_network_init(), this will become mandatory later.
x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
x264 [info]: profile High, level 3.1
x264 [info]: final ratefactor: 35.88
x264 [info]: using SAR=109/160
x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
x264 [info]: profile High, level 3.1
[flv @ 0x7f6d09133500] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[flv @ 0x7f6d09133500] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[flv @ 0x7f6d09133500] Packets are not in the proper order with respect to DTS
[0x7f6d08003808] avformat mux error: could not write frame (pts: 240002, dts: 40001) (pkt pts: 240, dts: 40)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that VLC can currently stream directly to RTMP. A couple sources that seem to confirm this: [videolanForumLink](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=97324), [wowzaForumLink](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?16655-RTP-%28VLC%29-to-RTMP-%28Wowza%29-to-flashPlayer%28Website%29).

However, it sounds like VLC may be able to be used in conjunction with other software - I've never tried this.

Alternatively, consider these common software tools (I've used these) used to stream to RTMP, though these may not directly do what you are trying to accomplish (these are good for streaming a webcam feed, or capturing a live video game for example).

- Open Broadcaster Software
- XSplit Broadcaster
- Flash Media Encoder